# Iterate through alphabet in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

in Obj-C it was possible to iterate through alphabet with:

```
for (char x='A'; x<='Z'; x++) {
```

In Swift this isn't possible. Any idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Swift, you can iterate chars on a string like this:

**Swift 2**

```
for char in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".characters {
    println(char)
}
```

**Swift 1.2**

```
for char in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" {
    println(char)
}
```

There might be a better way though.

Comment: Did you try something like for char in "a".."z"? I dont have SDK yet I couldn't try but just guessing. :)

Comment: @GokhanArik - Good thought, but it isn't working :( -- "cannot convert the expression's type 'Range<$T1>' to type '_SignedInteger"

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work :( I knew the above solution from Logan (thanks!), but I thought, there would be a way without typing the alphabet ;)

Comment: What about `for c in 'a'...'z' {}`? Using C char types instead of strings.

Comment: And what about the alphabet of other nations? The Norwegian alphabet is "abc...xyzæøå" (i.e. three extra characters at end). So it seems like your best option is to actually write out the alphabet, as @logan has suggested. In addition you can also use Array("abcde...xyzæøå") to get the array version directly.

Comment: does this still work in swift 2? [Value of type string has no generator] is what it says

Comment: @O.rka - No it does not.  Thanks for the catch, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 15):

It's slightly cumbersome, but the following works (Swift 3/4):

```
for value in UnicodeScalar("a").value...UnicodeScalar("z").value { print(UnicodeScalar(value)!) }
```

I suspect that the problem here is that the meaning of "a"..."z" could potentially be different for different string encodings.

---

(Older stuff)

Also cumbersome, but without the extra intermediate variable:

```
    for letter in map(UnicodeScalar("a").value...UnicodeScalar("z").value, {(val: UInt32) -> UnicodeScalar in return UnicodeScalar(val); })
    {
        println(letter)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, hope you don't mind the edit for Swift 4. You can reedit to make it your own style, of course.

Answer (score 10):

```
for i in 97...122{println(UnicodeScalar(i))}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4.2** version is much easier

```
for char in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" {
    print(char)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Updated for Swift 3.0 and higher**

```
let startChar = Unicode.Scalar("A").value
let endChar = Unicode.Scalar("Z").value

for alphabet in startChar...endChar {

    if let char = Unicode.Scalar(alphabet) {

        print(char)
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to save this char in string then do like this way
let startChar = Unicode.Scalar("a").value
let endChar = Unicode.Scalar("z").value

var s:String = ""
for alphabet in startChar...endChar {
    if let char = Unicode.Scalar(alphabet) {
        s += "\(char)"
    }
}
print(s)

Comment: if you want to save this char in string then do like this way
let startChar = Unicode.Scalar("a").value
let endChar = Unicode.Scalar("z").value

var s:String = ""
for alphabet in startChar...endChar {
    if let char = Unicode.Scalar(alphabet) {
        s += "\(char)"
    }
}
print(s)

Answer (score 3):

### Details

- Swift 5.3
- Version 12.4 (12D4e)

### Solution

```
extension ClosedRange where Bound == UnicodeScalar {
    func toArray() -> [UnicodeScalar] {
        (lowerBound.value...upperBound.value).compactMap { UnicodeScalar($0) }
    }
}

extension ClosedRange where Bound == String {
    func toArray() -> [UnicodeScalar]? {
        guard let lower = lowerBound.first?.unicodeScalars.first,
              let upper = upperBound.first?.unicodeScalars.first else { return nil }
        return (lower...upper).toArray()
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
("a"..."z").toArray() // option 1
(UnicodeScalar("a")...UnicodeScalar("z")).toArray() // option 2
```

Answer (score 2):

"Pure functional" **Swift 5** way:

```
(Unicode.Scalar("A").value...Unicode.Scalar("Z").value).forEach({
    let letter = Unicode.Scalar($0)!
    print(letter)
    /* do other stuff with letter here */
})
```

Comment: This is neither "pure" (`print` is a side effect), nor "functional" (`forEach` can only *ever* do side effects). But this is the best approach. IMO

Comment: That is why "pure functional" is in quotes.

Comment: You could make it properly functional by using map, at least

Comment: map() produces an array. Topic starter wanted to iterate. That's different task. My code iterates. So this is the solution.

Comment: More functional with compact map: `(Unicode.Scalar("a").value...Unicode.Scalar("z").value).compactMap {
         guard let unicode = Unicode.Scalar($0) else { return nil }
         return String(unicode)
      }`

Answer (score 1):

This solution works with Swift 3.0, and will either print out the values per OP request:

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".characters.flatMap { print($0) }
```

Or provide you with an array of letters:

```
let alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".characters.flatMap { $0.description }
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you try this one ?

```
for var myChar:CChar = 65 ; myChar <= 90 ; ++myChar {
      let x:String = String(format: "%c", myChar)
      println(x)
}
```

If you already know the character code

Comment: That "format" thing didn't work for me => `error: could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments`