# Better way to do this in a newer version of Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, coding-style

I want to iterate through the alphabet. This question gives a solution: [Iterate through alphabet in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019997/iterate-through-alphabet-in-swift)

However, the question is quite old. Is there a better, more elegant way to do so in the newest version of Swift (Specifically the first answer)?

Answer (score 3):

You can overload the operator `...` in the following way:

```
func ...(start: Character, end: Character) -> Array<UnicodeScalar> {

   var list : [UnicodeScalar] = []    
   let x = String(start).unicodeScalars
   let y = String(end).unicodeScalars

   for letter in map(String(start).unicodeScalars[x.startIndex].value...String(end).unicodeScalars[y.startIndex].value, {
    (val: UInt32) -> UnicodeScalar in return UnicodeScalar(val) }) {
       list.append(letter)
   }

   return list
}
```

And then you can do this in a nice way:

```
for x in "a"..."z" {
    println(x)
}
```

In the above code we should notice that always `start < end` because otherwise you can get the following error:

```
Can't form Range with end < start.
```

Answer (score 0):

Elegant, no. *Hackish*, yes.

```
    var char : Character
    for i in 65...90 {
        char = Character(UnicodeScalar(i))
        println(char)
    }
```

Comment: for i in 65..< 91 {  ...  }

Comment: I've edited my answer. Is this what you were suggesting @LeonardoSavioDabus ?